# How to change height of uiprogressview

Tags: ios, uiprogressview

I am trying to change the `UIProgressView` height through nib and programatic also. But it can't changed. So give some suggestion how to handle it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you try anything? What code do you try?

Comment: i think it will not possible .

Answer (score 2):

This is the trick :  chose scale according to the new height you want and then write this in your code :

```
self.progressView.tranform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, scale);
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Whatever I do on XCode 8 it always remains 1.5 height

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 3, it's changed to CGAffineTransform(scaleX: CGFloat, y: CGFloat). So code would be:

```
progressView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

`UIProgressView` has a fixed height. You can change the width though. There are a lot of custom progressviews [out there](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=progress) you could try.

Answer (score 0):

I've found another answer that works better for me. Set your width and height manually.

```
self.progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar]; [self.progressView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 11)];

[self.view addSubview:self.progressView];
```